# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find match between the canonical context path

Tags: spring-3

I am migrating some of my spring projects from Spring 2 to spring 3.0.4. Most of them are communicating within Rest calls. I see for some requests I am getting the below error .

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find match between the canonical context path [/servicename] and the URI presented by the user agent [_visitor=.......]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getContextPath(Request.java:2152)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getContextPath(RequestFacade.java:784)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.wrapRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:896)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:341)

If the API is called directly (using postman) its working. but when called through another service its failing.

Tomcat version resolved is Apache Tomcat/10.1.5

Could you pls help what could be the issue?

I rolled back to the previous Spring 2.* version and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be affect by [Tomcat bug #66488](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66488). Try upgrading to Tomcat 10.0.7 and see if your experience improves.

Answer (score 0):

> If the API is called directly (using postman) its working. but when called through another service its failing.

I think you can learn HTTP protocol and HTTP packet format first, then use some packet capture tools (such as tcpdump or wireshark) to capture HTTP request packets, and then analyze the difference between Postman's requests and those of other services.